# AngularJS detect checkbox value change in directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build an AngularJS directive which will detect an input checkbox value change, but for some reason the on change event is never triggered. Can someone please check my code and tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? Thanks

```
myApp.directive('supportAmntCb', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {    
            element.bind('click', function(){                               
                console.log('Value. '+ element[0].value); //this line is never reached...
            });    
        }

    };
});
```

HTML

When checked...

```
    <input id="s1" name="s1" type="checkbox" value="50" support-amnt-cb />
```

Unchecked...

```
    <input id="s1" name="s1" type="checkbox" value="0" support-amnt-cb />
```

Note: After several tests I noticed that with styling (CSS) applied to the checkboxes the directive can't detect value change....with styling (CSS) removed, the directive can easily detect change in value....can't figure out the relation between 'styling / css' and directive inability to detect change in value....any thoughts?

Comment: at the time of checking the checkbox what do you want

Comment: why don't you use ngChange directive ?

Comment: I'm not following why you need to this, you can use the existing [ng-change][1] directive


  [1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: Is the input dynamically created/ added to the DOM?

Comment: @Constantinos no, it is static but I just noticed that with CSS applied, it doesn't work...with no css applied it works smoothly, can't understand what's the relation between styling and directive not detecting the value change....any thoughts?

Comment: @Bixi even with mg-change it is not working, same reason for the styling problem I've mentioned in previous comment

Comment: An element might overlap the checkbox not allowing the click to go through? Just guessing.

Comment: change element.bind('click' to element.bind('change'

Comment: @MarioCampa tried change, click none worked

Comment: @Constantinos any idea how to detect the overlap?

Comment: Can you show us the CSS code you are using to style the checkbox. If it's something overlapping the checkbox try: z-index: 100;

Comment: Use your browser's web developer tools.